# Return only the unique words

Tags: r, string, function

Lets say i have a string and i only want unique words in the sentence as separate elements

```
 a = "an apple is an apple"
word <- function(a){
  
  words<- c(strsplit(a,split = " "))
  return(unique(words))
}

word(a)
```

This returns

```
[[1]]
[1] "an"    "apple" "is"    "an"    "apple"
```

and the output im expecting is

```
'an','apple','is'
```

what im doing wrong? really appreciate any help

Cheers!

Comment: `unique(strsplit(a, "\\s+")[[1]])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that wrapping `strsplit(.)` in `c(.)` does not change the fact that it is still a `list`, and `unique` will be operating at the list-level, not the word-level.

```r
c(strsplit(rep(a, 2), "\\s+"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "an"    "apple" "is"    "an"    "apple"
# [[2]]
# [1] "an"    "apple" "is"    "an"    "apple"
unique(c(strsplit(rep(a, 2), "\\s+")))
# [[1]]
# [1] "an"    "apple" "is"    "an"    "apple"
```

Alternatives:

1. If `length(a)` is always 1, then perhaps

   ```r
   unique(strsplit(a, "\\s+")[[1]])
   # [1] "an"    "apple" "is"
   ```
2. If `length(a)` can be 2 or more and you want a list of unique words *for each sentence*, then

   ```r
   a2 <- c("an apple is an apple", "a pear is a pear", "an orange is an orange")
   lapply(strsplit(a2, "\\s+"), unique)
   # [[1]]
   # [1] "an"    "apple" "is"   
   # [[2]]
   # [1] "a"    "pear" "is"  
   # [[3]]
   # [1] "an"     "orange" "is"
   ```

   (Note: this always returns a `list`, regardless of the number of sentences in the input.)
3. if `length(a)` can be 2 ore more and you want a unique words *across all sentences*, then

   ```r
   unique(unlist(strsplit(a2, "\\s+")))
   # [1] "an"     "apple"  "is"     "a"      "pear"   "orange"
   ```

   (Note: this method also works well when `length(a)` is 1.)

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, based on `stringr::str_split`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

a %>% str_split("\\s+") %>% unlist %>% unique

#> [1] "an"    "apple" "is"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
unique(unlist(strsplita, " ")))
```